# Cross-cultural use of Americanism?

Tags: phrases, british-english

I understand the scathing phrase 'You piece of garbage!' to be an Americanism. Is the phrase used fairly much in Britain, too?

Comment: Unlike the [Google 4-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=You+piece+of+garbage&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CYou%20piece%20of%20garbage%3B%2Cc0) for the expression from their American(?) corpus, [that for the British English corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=You+piece+of+garbage&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) flatlines. Which is what I (a Brit) would expect.

Comment: But it's not really all that commonly used in AmE either

Comment: Piece of garbage: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/piece+of+garbage

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Of course, "garbage" is less than half as common in BE as in AE.  Apparently didn't make it across the pond until the 70s.

Comment: As you'd expect, the runaway top choice for ***You piece of XXXX!*** is ***shit***. But a distant second is ***filth***, followed by ***trash*** (another "Americanism"). Finally, ***garbage*** - not even in the top 3.

Comment: [The chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=You+piece+of+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2CYou%20piece%20of%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BYou%20piece%20of%20shit%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BYou%20piece%20of%20filth%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BYou%20piece%20of%20trash%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BYou%20piece%20of%20garbage%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2CYou%20piece%20of%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BYou%20piece%20of%20shit%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BYou%20piece%20of%20filth%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BYou%20piece%20of%20trash%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BYou%20piece%20of%20garbage%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Over here (UK) a **garbage** collection is mostly what a computer system does to reclaim idle memory. It's not particulary offensive, generally meaning something that no longer has any use.

Comment: @WeatherVane - That's because computer jargon got trashed by 'Mericans!

Comment: @HotLicks I get your irony, but a lot of that jargon came this way across the pond.

Comment: To perhaps clarify a little, the term "garbage" has been used in the US to mean "household waste" ever since I can remember (and that's going back to the 50s).  The truck that comes by to pick up the waste is (and always has been) a "garbage truck", and the person operating it is a "garbage man".  (Ngram finds "garbage truck" to be roughly 5 times more common in AE than in BE, and the term in AE goes back to the 20s.)

Comment: [This reference](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Municipal_Engineering/dBg_AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22garbage+truck%22&pg=PA145&printsec=frontcover) shows that "garbage truck" was already a fairly common term in the US in 1917.

Comment: @HotLicks in UK household waste was called **refuse** and the vehicle a **refuse lorry**. The house's **dustbin** was carried by the **dustman** (hear the [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6HZU-z3j8I)) and tipped into the lorry (a dusty job because of ashes from fires). They were replaced by **rubbish bags** some decades ago, collected in a similar way, but they would be torn open by birds and rats etc. That changed to wheeled bins called **wheelie bins** which the householder brings to the edge of the property. The collector is now called a **bin man** and the vehicle a **bin lorry**.